# Connecting to an existing sqlite database to an instance of QSqlDatabase

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtsql, qsqldatabase

I'm having trouble connecting an existing database to an instance of QSqlDatabase. Is it possible to do this?

I've read through a good amount of posts related to this issue; most of them imply that it's at least possible to do this. However, I haven't been able to do it. It seems like a pretty straightforward process as well.

```
    db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
    db.setDatabaseName("moves.sqlite")  # this is the name of the database. It's on the same line directory as this code 
    # db.setDatabaseName(os.path.abspath("./moves.sqlite"))

    opened = db.open()
    if not opened:
        print("database not found!")
        return
```

I end up getting the print message "database not found!". I should be able to get the database opened and perform queries on it. Have I got the QSqlDatabase class completely wrong?

**Edit:** At the request of @musicmante in the comments below, I added these lines:

```
    print(db.lastError().databaseText())
    print(db.lastError().driverText())
```

For both, the output was "driver not loaded. I went ahead and added:

```
    print(QSqlDatabase.drivers())
```

This got me an empty list.

Comment: After the failed open, what is the output of `db.lastError().databaseText()` and `db.lastError().driverText()`?

Comment: @musicamante I just ran that and the output of both those statements is "driver not loaded".

Comment: @ThaNyneTray How strange, the sqlite driver should come by default

Comment: @eyllanesc I think the problem came from the fact that I was working in a conda environment. Somehow, the QSqlDrivers are not installed with conda's PyQt5. I switched over to pip and it works perfectly now.

Comment: @ThaNyneTray It is difficult to help you if you do not indicate that you are using conda, for the next occasion point it out in your question. I recommend you report the bug to conda.

Comment: @eyllanesc I will point it out next time. I didn't think to point it out, but I will next time. Thanks

Comment: @ThaNyneTray Instead of adding it as a comment in your post, place it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Ended up finding the root of the problem. I was working on in project within a `conda` environment previously. I switched over to a virtualenv environment, reinstalled `PyQt5` with `pip` this time, and everything worked fine. It seems that the `QSqlDatabase` drivers are not included with the `conda` `PyQt5` installation. However, it works fine when installed through `pip`.